# Installing MySQLdb on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm having all sorts of trouble trying to instal MySQLdb (1.2.2) on snow leopard. I am running python 2.5.1 and MySQL 5.1 32bit.

Python and MySQL are running just fine.

I've also installed django 1.2.1, although I don't think thats all that important, but wanted to give an idea of the stack i'm trying to install. I am using python 2.5.x as my webhost only has that version as an option and I want to be as close to my production env as possible.

anyway...

After following many of the existing articles and tutorials which mention modifying _mysql.c and setup_posix.py etc, I am still running into trouble.

Here is my stack trace:

xxxxxxx-mbp:MySQL-python-1.2.2 xxxxxxx$ sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5
gcc -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,2,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.2 -I/usr/local/mysql-5.1.48-osx10.6-x86/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-i386-2.5/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch i386 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:112,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/unicodeobject.h:118,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h:83,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from _mysql.c:35:
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.48-osx10.6-x86/include/my_config.h:1062:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/pyconfig.h:724:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You might want to give [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) a try. Uninstall your existing MySQL installation, then do `sudo port install mysql5-server-devel python25 py25-mysql`. It will tell you how to set up your new MySQL server at the end of the installation. You'll also need to make sure you're using the MacPorts Python installation instead of your system one (you can use python-select for that).

Answer (score 1):

Rather late for the original question, but in case others - like me - are encountering the mystery of a missing stdarg.h, see below. I'm using MacOS X 10.7.3, MySQL 5.5.20, Python 2.7.2, MySQL-python-1.2.3.

My error message:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
```

The following blog post saved me:
    http://packetcloud.net/2009/09/22/installing-mysql-python-module-for-python-262-on-snow-leopard-using-xcode/

Summarizing the key bit:

Open up /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h

Replace the line:

```
#include_next <stdarg.h>
```

With:

```
#include_next </Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/stdarg.h>
```

Then things work smoothly:

```
> sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py build
> sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually install packages like this with MacPorts. It's package management software that handles all the downloading, configuring and installing for you.  It's just like emerge on gentoo or apt-get on debian.

Make sure you have Xcode installed and [install macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php). Once you've got that installed, fire up the terminal and install mysql by typing:

```
$ sudo port install mysql5-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this one for days myself and finally gave up.

I switched to postgres. It works pretty well with django on snow leopard,
with one minor problem. For some reason auto_inc pk ids don't get assigned
to some models. I solved the problem by randomly assigning an id from a large
random range, and relying on the unique column designation to prevent collisions.

My production server is linux. Mysql and postgres install fine on it.

In fact, many on the #django irc channel recommended running a virtual linux
instance on the mac to get around my mysql install problems on it.

Comment: Simply running Linux in a VM came to my mind as well. I was afraid it might sound smarmy, though! I do think that is the best plan esp. since the webserver probably runs Linux.